# Spring Config property not being populated on a certain server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, static

I have this initialized in a Spring MVC project, but the BASE_URL is always empty.  On three other servers it works just fine.  Is there something going on with initialization of this class and the static variable?

**BaseClass.java**

```
public final String BASE_URL = SystemConfiguration.restHost;
```

**SystemConfiguration.java**

```
public static String restHost;

public void setRestHost(String restHost) {
    SystemConfiguration.restHost = restHost;
}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<property name="RestHost">
    <value>${restHost:https://example.com}</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it had to do with a static variable being assigned to the final variable.  We just referenced the `SystemConfiguration.restHost` directly in the code and all worked fine.  I am assuming the spring beans were being loaded in a different order on this server then the others that worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is Java after all. Static field are initialized when the class they belong to is loaded and initialized.

If `BaseClass` is loaded before your application loads the application context and sets the field from the `SystemConfiguration` bean, then the `BASE_URL` will be initialized to `null` since `SystemConfiguration.restHost` is by default also `null`.

You should really consider changing your design. There's no reason to have any `static` fields. Spring can handle all your configuration values as beans or bean values.

Comment: In any case, do you believe that on the other three servers the initialization was correct during loading of Spring, and on this server for some reason it wasnt?

Comment: @MikeFlynn What's different between the deployments?

Comment: Nothing should be different.  I dont have access to the server but I was told nothing.  I could compare the logs they gave us and mine to see if there is a difference in loading that class but since its fixed I dont feel like it anymore haha.  When I say no difference, no difference in their dev server.  We also have our own dev server along with our local environment and it works fine.

Comment: @MikeFlynn I don't see what else it could be. It's a `final` variable. It can only be assigned once. If it's `null`, then `SystemConfiguration.restHost` was `null`. If it was `null`, it means the `ApplicationContext` wasn't loaded yet. Consider using things like `@Value` instead.